# University project : setTimeout problems

Tags: javascript

i'm studying Informatic Engineering at Pisa, in Italy, and one of my exams consists into creating a web service. My choice was a little game coded in Javascript. There is a flash based game called " Hobo " that it's similar to mine. My problem is :

I have to create a function that restore the idle animation of the enemies. I need that this function it's called inside another function ( `attack`  function ). The `restore_idle_gif` function set a `setTimeout` that after 800ms restores the original animation but I get the following trouble : it there is more than 1 enemy, that function restores the animation of the last enemy that attacks.

The code is :

```
function enemy_class ( ..... )
{
    // Variables

    // Methods
    this.attack_method = attack_fun ;
    this.move_method   = move_fun   ;

    // Movement timer and Attack Cooldown ( they works as i wanted )
    this.move_timer=setInterval(this.move_enemy.bind(this),( 1000/this.movement_speed));
    this.attack_timer=setInterval(this.attack_enemy.bind(this),( 1000/this.attack_speed));
}

function attack_fun()
{
   // Some stuff that we don't need for my problem
   if ( chance_of_attack == true )
   {
      nemico = document.getElementById( this.get_enemy_id() );
      nemico.setAttribute( "src", "Media/images/enemy_attack.gif" ) ;
      damage_hero ( this ) ;
      restore_idle_gif( this ) ;
   }
}

function damage_hero( that ) 
{
   // works
}
```

And finally the EVIL function that it's mindblowing me :

```
function restore_idle_gif( nemico_che_attacca )
{
      var restore_timer = setTimeout ( function() { var restore = document.getElementById( nemico_che_attacca.get_enemy_id() ) ; restore.setAttribute ( "src", "Media/images/enemy.gif" ) ; } , 800 ) ;

}
```

The rest of the code works fine, except this "glitch". I really need it to work because i need to create the code for all the remaining animations. Please help me with that code or give me ideas / alternative solutions. Sorry for my bad english and for bad formatting text, it's my first time in Stackoverflow.

Comment: In `attack_fun` I see that you select the attacking enemy using `document.getElementById( this.get_enemy_id() )`. In `restore_idle_gif` you switched to `document.getElementById( nemico_che_attacca.get_enemy_id() )`. Shouldn't it be `that.get_enemy_id()` instead ?

Comment: Sorry i tiped my question wrong, i used "nemico_che_attacca" ad parameter in my code!

Comment: Also to note: when asking questions on Stack Overflow (welcome !), it is considered good practice to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code.

Comment: Next time i'll keep that in mind, ty!

Comment: However @ThibWeb , it don't work. I know that the problem it's within setTimeout because i lose the context of the calling object, but i don't know how to run it correctly. Any tips or solutions? :(

Comment: Hard to say from the gode examples you provide, but whenever I read phrases like "that function restores the animation of the last enemy that attacks." I think of closure issues. Are you having some logic that is running in a for loop prior to those examples? That usually can lead to things affecting the last item in the loop instead of the expected one.

Comment: No @MartinHansen, in attack_fun there are only conditionals, and in the rest of the program i just run some setInterval. If i just have one enemy on the screen all works, but the problem comes with 2 or more enemies. I think that the problem is that when the second enemy attack with attack_fun, the variable restore_timer it's resetted with the new enemy. I really have no ideas to clear this problem. :/

Comment: Maybe try `setTimeout ( function(id) { var restore = document.getElementById(id) ; restore.setAttribute ( "src", "Media/images/enemy.gif" ) ; } , 800, nemico_che_attacca.get_enemy_id()) ;`, where `id` will be equal to the last parameter given to setTimeout (see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)).

Comment: @ThibWeb i'll try as you say, tomorrow i'll let you know if it works. Ty man!